# Having trouble writing a MongoDB aggregation query that requires the use of grouping

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that stores user activity data pertaining to whether users up vote or down vote on a select list of keywords as they relate to a catalogue of titles. I need to execute an aggregation query in Mongo that gives me the cumulative score of each keyword that is tied to a title across all users - an up vote is represented by vote: true and a downvote by vote: false

Used the unwind operator as my first step followed by the group by but this is where I'm lost as I'm not sure whether to group by a combination of the titleId, keyword and vote; just the titleId and keyword or just the titleId. Here is a sample of what the data looks like in the collection -

Expecting to see one document grouped by titleId at the end of the aggregation query with a an array of objects, where each object contains a keyword and the cumulative vote total for that keyword in the context of that title.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d2eb0b20e91d1941540e2b5"), 
    "titleId" : "111222", 
    "userId" : "993f1e69-c6b0-44eb-a8a6-5db5dc42d425", 
    "activity" : [
        {
            "keyword" : "Road Trip", 
            "vote" : true
        }, 
        {
            "keyword" : "Friendship", 
            "vote" : true
        },
        {
            "keyword" : "Family Movie", 
            "vote" : true
        }
    ]
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d38fd270e91d1941559bee0"), 
    "titleId" : "111222", 
    "userId" : "f92c7118-8930-4d30-8e07-8363737a6866", 
    "activity" : [
        {
            "keyword" : "Road Trip", 
            "vote" : false
        }, 
        {
            "keyword" : "Adventure", 
            "vote" : true
        }, 
        {
            "keyword" : "Family Movie", 
            "vote" : true
        }
    ]
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d38fd270e91d1941559bee0"), 
    "titleId" : "111222", 
    "userId" : "f92c7118-8930-4d30-8e07-8363737a6866", 
    "activity" : [
        {
            "keyword" : "Road Trip", 
            "vote" : false
        }, 
        {
            "keyword" : "Adventure", 
            "vote" : false
        }, 
        {
            "keyword" : "Family Movie", 
            "vote" : false
        }
    ]
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d2eb0b20e91d1941540e2b5"), 
    "titleId" : "444222", 
    "userId" : "993f1e69-c6b0-44eb-a8a6-5db5dc42d425", 
    "activity" : [
        {
            "keyword" : "Educational film and videos", 
            "vote" : true
        }, 
        {
            "keyword" : "Space", 
            "vote" : true
        }
    ]
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d38fd270e91d1941559bee0"), 
    "titleId" : "444222", 
    "userId" : "f92c7118-8930-4d80-8e07-8363737a6866", 
    "activity" : [
        {
            "keyword" : "Action", 
            "vote" : false
        }, 
        {
            "keyword" : "Adventure", 
            "vote" : false
        }, 
        {
            "keyword" : "Sci Fi", 
            "vote" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Expecting to see one document grouped by titleId with a an array of objects, where each object contains a keyword and the cumulative vote total for that keyword in the context of that title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$activity"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":{
                "titleId":"$titleId",
                "keyword":"$activity.keyword"
            },
            "votes":{
                $sum:{
                    $cond:[
                        {
                            $eq:["$activity.vote",true]
                        },
                        1,
                        -1
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$_id.titleId",
            "titleId":{
                $first:"$_id.titleId"
            },
            "activity":{
                $push:{
                    "keyword":"$_id.keyword",
                    "votes":"$votes"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{
    "titleId" : "111222",
    "activity" : [
        {
            "keyword" : "Road Trip",
            "votes" : -1
        },
        {
            "keyword" : "Adventure",
            "votes" : 0
        },
        {
            "keyword" : "Friendship",
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "keyword" : "Family Movie",
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "titleId" : "444222",
    "activity" : [
        {
            "keyword" : "Adventure",
            "votes" : -1
        },
        {
            "keyword" : "Sci Fi",
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "keyword" : "Action",
            "votes" : -1
        },
        {
            "keyword" : "Educational film and videos",
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "keyword" : "Space",
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**Aggregation stages:**

- Stage I: Unwind 'activity' array. Now there is one document per element of the array
- Stage II: Grouping on the basis of title ID and activity keyword and
  calculating the votes count. 1 for upvote and -1 for the downvote.
- Stage III: Grouping only on the basis of title ID and merging all activities into an array
- Stage IV: Eliminating unnecessary fields from the output

Comment: Many thanks MrS.Sharma, but there’s 1 small wrinkle. In the above solution, a true vote and a false vote for the same keyword are increasing the count by 1. I actually need a false vote to decrement the count by 1 - so for example, in the case of title 111222, the keyword road trip has 2 false votes and 1 true vote, which means the total count should be -1.The above solution however gives 2, because it’s adding 1+1 for 1 true vote and 1 false vote. The last false vote was excluded because the third document for this title had all false values and the match statement filtered this out.Thoughts?

Comment: @raja In the query, only upvotes are counted... but because of the wrong data set, you see the unexpected output even for upvotes. Updating the query to decrement for downvote too, along with the updated output. Thanks :)